# Browser notification onclick event doesn't get fired in chrome when tag option is used

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I have made a chat application, in that i am notifiying user when a message comes using "Notification" api.

Also I have used "tag" to remove duplicate notification if user has two duplicate tabs open.

Now, whenever user has two tabs opened and one notification is replaced by the same notification tag, in Chrome i am unable to get the "onclick" callback when user clicks on that notification.

```
var notificationObj = new Notification("Title", {
    body: "Body",
    tag: 'Tag'
});
notificationObj.onclick = function () {
    alert('onclick called');
};
```

Also tried below,

```
notificationObj.addEventListener("onclick", function (event) {
    alert('onclick called');
});
```

So my question is, why the notificaion.onclick won't get triggered in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Browser bug:
check the link.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=923782